# Teradata Assistant - Export To CSV File

Tags: teradata

In Teradata Assistant I run a query and make export to CSV file.
This CSV file needs to be imported in Access database.
Problem is - only files, which are smaller than 2 GB, can be imported into Access database.
So the question is - is it possible to cut the big CSV file into smaller pieces (for example 2GB), during the export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You Export the query to CSV file (2 Go) from **Teradata Assistant** : File name : **export_file.csv**

2) You open the Shell console. I Prefer MSYS [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS)

3) You type the command in the console : `split -l 2000 export_file.csv`  (**2000 : number of lines/file**)

4) You will have your file split into several small files

5) You can after import this files in **Access database**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use shell utilities

Use split - e.g. to split a file every 2000 lines (should give you many files):

```
split -l 2000 <file_name>
```

For more : visit [split-properties](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split)

Comment: can I do it somehow in Assistant?
If yes how? CAn I add some statement or similar?

Comment: please send me a detailed description on how to do the split.